# Java prevent users from entering anything except integers

Tags: java

My intentions are to take a string input from a user, and only accept integer values. Maybe what I have is not the best approach to this and if that's the case let me know how I should go about changing my program. Lets say the user enters the values such as `1 2 3 4 a 5`. How do I go about preventing this little error.

```
String[] intVal;
String inputValues;
int[] numbers = new int[20];
int count = 0;

InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);

System.out.print("Enter up to 20 integer values here: ");
inputValues = input.readLine();
intVal = inputValues.split("\\s");

for(int i = 0; i < intVal.length; i++){
   numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(intVal[i]);
   count++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are asking the wrong question. When you code, don’t think like "how do I prevent the user", but like "how should my program behave when the user will..." It is not possible that you force the user into entering 20 integers, so maybe, when he does wrong, you could ask him again... by putting the  `readLine` and the `parseInt` into a `while (count < intVal)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(String s)` throws a `NumberFormatException` if the input was not a number (see the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) on `Integer.parseInt(String s)`).

You could do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < intVal.length; i++) {
  try {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(intVal[i]);
    count++;
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println(i + " is not a number. Ignoring this value..."); // Or do something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many possible solutions, one of them is catching the exception that `parseInt` throws and ask the user to input another sequence.

But I would use [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) and [`hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) instead, and ignore any character that's not a digit.